# What Filesystems Are Supported by Lenovo And Dell Laptops on EFI System Partition?

Tags: boot, filesystems, uefi, efi

According to the [UEFI specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_8_final.pdf#G17.1019485) (13.3.1.1 File System Format) an EFI firmware must support `FAT12`, `FAT16` and `FAT32` file systems for the EFI system partition (ESP). However, the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_system_partition) states that "*any conformant vendor can optionally add support for additional file systems*".

Does one know of a vendor supporting additional file systems, like `ext2/3/4`? Or does one even (successfully) use a journaling file system on an ESP?

In particular I am interested in Lenovo and Dell laptops from 2017 or newer.

Comment: Most likely it would at most support NTFS additionally. Unlikely exFAT, hardly any Linux filesystems.

Comment: Reason? How the world works.

Answer (score 6):

Any vendor that will support in the UEFI firmware additional file systems like
ext2/3/4 will be strictly non-standard and will require a specialized UEFI firmware.
This is unlikely to exist (except on Apple computers).

The
[UEFI Specification Version 2.5](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%202_5.pdf),
published by UEFI.org, April 2015, says this in
section "12.3 File System Format", pp. 536:

> EFI encompasses the use of FAT32 for a system partition, and FAT12 or
>   FAT16 for removable media. The FAT32 system partition is identified by
>   an OSType value other than that used to identify previous versions of
>   FAT. **This unique partition type distinguishes an EFI defined file
>   system from a normal FAT file system**. The file system supported by EFI
>   includes support for long file names.
>
> **The definition of the EFI file system will be maintained by specification and will not evolve over time** to deal with errata or
>   variant interpretations in OS file system drivers or file system
>   utilities. Future enhancements and compatibility enhancements to FAT
>   will not be automatically included in EFI file systems. **The EFI file
>   system is a target that is fixed by the EFI specification**, and other
>   specifications explicitly referenced by the EFI specification.

Please note that the above UEFI Specification does not anywhere
make reference to any other file-system format than its own.

The above applies to the base UEFI implementation.
To extend the UEFI is always possible by loading during the boot a
[EFI/UEFI file system driver](https://efi.akeo.ie/).
(I don't know where/if the drivers in this link are actually used.)

For example, to access an NTFS partition you can from the EFI Shell issue
commands such as:

```
load ntfs_x6efi
map -r
```

However, all drivers and bootloaders are loaded from the EFI partition,
which is always identified by its unique partition ID and so must be formatted
according to the EFI specifications that are compatible only with FAT32/16/12.
Support for other file-system formats can only come after that the UEFI
firmware was loaded, after it found its FAT partition, and after it starts
executing the configuration files that it finds inside.

As far as I know, Apple is the only computer manufacturer that created a specialized
UEFI version, for supporting HFS+. The standard EFI partition is still present
in Apple computers,
but is usually left empty and is then bypassed in the normal course of events.

Comment: You can also use `startup.nsh` to script the loading of the drivers and then calling upon the boot loader .

Comment: +1 since this might indeed be the correct answer. However, I am still hoping someone comes up with a counterexample.

Comment: @dirdi - There isn’t one; Windows EFI support doesn’t support anything other than FAT32; Since Apple is the other OEM that does not sell Windows machines; They are the only manufacturer that implemented support for HFS+ because Apple developed HFS+ they can support it 100%;

Comment: Apple also supports exFAT ESP, but it's because they use EFI and not UEFI which is newer

Comment: @Ramhound I do not plan to install Windows.

Answer (score -1):

It is always safest to use an FAT32 partition for UEFI.

You don't know what other computers will be accessing the partition, and FAT32 is the best supported for the purpose.

Windows 10 and several other systems require at least 550MB for the UEFI partition so this eliminates FAT12 from the options and makes FAT16 no longer favorable.

Comment: What other computer beside the one containing the drive holding the ESP would ever access it?

Comment: @dirdi - It doesn’t matter;  if you plan on installing Windows you must use FAT32.  Dell nor Lenovo UEFI implementation supports ext2/3/4

Comment: @Ramhound I do not plan to install Windows.

Comment: @dirdi - Dell and Lenovo are primary Microsoft OEMs which means their UEFI firmware support will be limited to what Windows supports.